# How to Redirect PHP page to another PHP page inside a new folder in an FTP server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ftp

Hi so I need to redirect this php page:

```
wwd_energy-efficiency.php
```

*This file is in the main views folder*

to this url path:

```
http://www.domain.com/renewable-energy/energy-efficiency
```

*This path, I created a new directory folder 'renewable-energy' and duplicated wwd_energy-efficiency.php then renamed it energy-efficiency*

I used 3 types of redirection - NOTHING WORKED

**(1) .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wwd_energy-efficiency\.php$ http://www.domain.com/renewable-energy/energy-efficiency [L,R=301]
```

**Returns 404**

**(2) php header**

```
<?php
header("Location: renewable-energy/energy-efficiency.php");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/renewable-energy/energy-efficiency");
?>
```

**Returns 404**

**(3) META **

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.domain.com/renewable-energy/energy-efficiency">
```

**Returns 404**

I'M GUESSING THAT REDIRECTION MIGHT NOT BE THE PROBLEM OR IS THERE A MISTAKE IN CREATING A FOLDER IN AN FTP SERVER? IM NOT REALLY SURE NOW. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: does the url  " http://www.domain.com/renewable-energy/energy-efficiency " work when you enter it in browser's location?

Comment: @Starkeen No, it's not working. :/ But the folder 'renewable-energy' and 'energy-efficiency' php file are there in the server.

Comment: Obviously, this is a permission issue on your folder

Comment: @JustinIurman Oh so that's why. Alright thanks! I'll just contact our server owner :)